# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, create-react-app

I am doing a simple exercise in React. The goal of the exercise is to simply:

- Randomly draw fruit from the array
- Log the message “I’d like one RANDOMFRUIT, please.”
- Log the message “Here you go: RANDOMFRUIT”
- Log the message “Delicious! May I have another?”
- Remove the fruit from the array of fruits
- Log the message “I’m sorry, we’re all out. We have FRUITSLEFT left.

While running this code, I've encountered the following error. For some reason, the "length" seems to be the problem.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
Module../src/index.js
C:/Users/jaina/Desktop/ReactAPPS/exercise1/exercise-one/src/index.js:15
  12 | // Remove the fruit from the array of fruits
  13 | let remaining = remove(foods, fruit);
  14 | // Log the message “I’m sorry, we’re all out. We have FRUITSLEFT left.”
> 15 | console.log(`I’m sorry, we’re all out. We have ${remaining.length} other foods left.`);
  16 |
```

It also says `__webpack_require__` along with other webpack warnings. But I am assuming the main reason for not running is that "length" is undefined.

**index.js**

```
import foods from './foods';
import { choice, remove } from './helpers';

// Randomly draw a fruit from the array
let fruit = choice(foods);
// Log the message “I’d like one RANDOMFRUIT, please.”
console.log(`I’d like one ${fruit}, please.`);
// Log the message “Here you go: RANDOMFRUIT”
console.log(`Here you go: ${fruit}`);
// Log the message “Delicious! May I have another?”
console.log('Delicious! May I have another?');
// Remove the fruit from the array of fruits
let remaining = remove(foods, fruit);
// Log the message “I’m sorry, we’re all out. We have FRUITSLEFT left.”
console.log(`I’m sorry, we’re all out. We have ${remaining.length} other foods left.`);
```

**Foods.js**

```
const foods = [
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "",
];

export default foods;
```

**helper.js**

```
function choice(items){
    let idx = Math.floor(Math.random()* items.length);
}

function remove(items, item){
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        if(items[i] === item){
            return [ ...items.slice(0,i), ...items.slice(i+1)];
        }
    }
}

export {choice, remove};
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess that `if` condition never matches, so it never gets inside the block and never runs the `return`. So, it just implicitly returns `undefined`.

Comment: also validate your data ```${remaining && remaining.length}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `helper.js`, if your function `remove` does not find anything, it will return undefined. Then, when you say...

```
console.log(`I’m sorry, we’re all out. We have ${remaining.length} other foods left.`);
```

...you're assuming `remaining` is an Array, but it's actually undefined.

Try putting `return items;` at the end of the `remove` function, after the for loop.

Comment: Thank you so much. I added that and the program worked successfully. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, return `items` in case nothing in found in the `remove` function.

```
function remove(items, item){
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        if(items[i] === item){
            return [ ...items.slice(0,i), ...items.slice(i+1)];
        }
    }
    // change this to whatever you want in case it was able to find item to remove
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be here:

```
function choice(items){
    let idx = Math.floor(Math.random()* items.length);
}
```

So `let fruit = choice(foods)`, fruit will always be undefined.

try to return the value of the helper function like this:

```
function choice(items){
   let fruitIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()* items.length);
   return items[fruitIndex];
}
```

You should also find the index of the choice and return the fruit, otherwise the `choice` will return only a number.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your choice and remove function

```js
function choice(items) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length);
}

function remove(items, item) {
    return items.filter(e => e !== item);
};
```